# get img src with jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

This is my html

```
<script src="/ClientScripts/swfobject.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<div class="contentDetails">
<div id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentDetailsBodyDivision" class="body">
<div align="justify">

<p align="center"><img width="500" height="352" alt="MVM315" src="/UserUpload/Image/1(825).jpg" /></p>
<p align="center"><img width="500" height="352" alt="MVM315" src="/UserUpload/Image/2(598).jpg" /></p>
```

How can i get {`src="/UserUpload/Image/1(825).jpg"`} with jsoup ?

I have this code but not working

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements mElements = doc.select("div[id^=ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentDetailsBodyDivision]");
Result = mElements.get(0).tagName("img").toString();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
 Element imageElement = document.select("img").first();

 String absoluteUrl = imageElement.absUrl("src");  //absolute URL on src

 String srcValue = imageElement.attr("src");  // exact content value of the attribute.
```

More info here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

Comment: I have a lot of src in my html I just want my src that is in div with id "ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentDetailsBodyDivision"

Comment: then you have to first select the div...THEN from the Element (Document) of the selection..you do the select("img")..like this:  Element imageElement = DIV_DOCUMENT.select("img").first();

Comment: can you write the cod ? i don't understand

Comment: You can find examples here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Element img = document.select("img").first()
String src = img.attr("src");
```

For more info see this: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html